# Migrating SQL Server databases to Azure Data Studio on MAC

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, migration

Due to unrelated reasons, I have to move from a Microsoft Windows machine to a MACPro. On my windows machine, I have a SQL server installed with several databases.  All databases have been backed up to storage.  On my MAC, I installed Docker and I am running SQL Server for Ubuntu with Azure Data Studio as my interface.  The installation works great but my question now is: Is there any way to attach the Sql Server Databases in storage from my windows environment to the new installation on MACPRO?

My windows SQL Server was 2017 and my new MAC version is 2019 in case that matters.

I see some tutorials on importing flat files etc. but not where you can import (attach, restore etc.) a database from a SQL Server environment in Windows to a MAC (or Linux) environment but hoping someone has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just backup your database using "Generate Scripts" to create a SQL script with the schema and data. Then use the generated SQL file to create a new database in your new environment?

In SSMS, you right-click the database, then select `Tasks->Generate Scripts...` In the dialog you click the `Advanced` button and choose to `Schema and data` under `types of data`:

[image: Advanced Scripting Options]

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention: You can target different RDBMS engines when you create the scripts, so under `Script for the database engine type` you can select `Microsoft Azure SQL Database` where I have shown `Stand-alone instance`.

Comment: The scripting method does work but is extremely slow so if you have a database with several tables and approaching 1 GB, it can take hours before import...but, if that is what needs to be done, I can always run these overnight. Thank you for the suggestion!