# Can't restore backup or move mdf file from upper compatability level to lower one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I want to downgrade a `.mdf` file or backup file from SQL Server 2017 to 2016. I can't do that by changing a compatibility level! How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have SQL-Server 2017 or higher available? If so, you should be able to use SSMS to generate scripts for V2016. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678075/migrating-sql-server-databases-to-azure-data-studio-on-mac/57678173#57678173 on how to generate the scripts.

Comment: You ***CANNOT*** with any method, trick, workaround or tool do this. Period. You just simply ***CANNOT*** restore / attach a newer SQL Server database file or backup to an earlier version. That just cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no way to restore newer version backup to an older version.
2. You can do a restore to newer environment and then transfer the structure, code and data to old server. The fastest way to transfer the data is to use "SQL Server Export-Import" module, but it might be tricky.